# When I run my program that contain NAudio lib appear the following error that (WaveInterop.mmioStringToFOURCC) was not accessible

Tags: c#, audio, wav, naudio

When I run my program that contains [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library the following error appear that was "not accessible due to its protection level".

```
public void ReadWaveHeader(Stream stream)
{
    this.dataChunkPosition = -1;
    this.waveFormat = null;
    this.riffChunks = new List<RiffChunk>();
    this.dataChunkLength = 0;

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
    ReadRiffHeader(br);
    this.riffSize = br.ReadUInt32(); // Read the file size (minus 8 bytes)

    if (br.ReadInt32() != WaveInterop.mmioStringToFOURCC("WAVE", 0))
    {
        throw new FormatException("Not a WAVE file - no WAVE header");
    }

    if (isRf64)
    {
        ReadDs64Chunk(br);
    }

    int dataChunkID = WaveInterop.mmioStringToFOURCC("data", 0);
    int formatChunkId = WaveInterop.mmioStringToFOURCC("fmt ", 0);

    // Sometimes a file has more data than is specified after the RIFF header
    long stopPosition = Math.Min(riffSize + 8, stream.Length);
```

Comment: the problem was in waveintrop

Comment: what OS are you running on?

Comment: window 8 and the problem was in WaveInterop.mmioStringToFOURCC please i need your help and think u

Comment: is it a Windows store app?

Comment: i think that my laptop was HP and its the only windows that use to it

Comment: I'm sorry for taking your time but i need your help I'm master student and the first step in my project is to open audio file(wav) and reading it's header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a Windows Store application you are making, then you can't call mmioStringToFOURCC. The [NAudio 1.7 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio) contains a preview quality Windows Store assembly that doesn't call mmioStringToFOURCC. However, NAudio's Windows Store support isn't quite complete yet.

If you mean that you have a compile error because you are trying to call WaveInterop.mmioStringToFOURCC from outside of NAudio, then you can't because WaveInterop is internal to NAudio. Not all of the NAudio internals are made externally visible to keep the overall API surface area down. You could easily put the interop signature into your own code:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int mmioStringToFOURCC([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String s, int flags);
```